# r plot correlation matrix from file with correlation

Tags: r, plot, correlation

After try to find a solution, I didn't.
I have a .txt file with a correlation matrix which was previously created from other records. It looks like this:

```
    CXCL9   IL2RG   TAP1
CXCL9   1
IL2RG   0.828   1
TAP1    0.605   0.631   1
CD274   0.564   0.57    0.679
LAG3    0.624   0.676   0.681
```

I am trying to generate a correlogram, an for that I've done this:

```
m <- read.table("file.txt", sep="\t", header=TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
mymatrix <- as.matrix(m)
corrplot(mymatrix, type = "lower", method="number")
```

And I get this message:

```
Error in corrplot(mymatrix, type = "lower") : The matrix is not in [-1, 1]!
```

How can I do a simple correlogram with this data? (maybe doing a heatmap?)
The desired output:
[image]

Comment: Two things pop into mind; 1) your correlation matrix is not square - this might be a requirement for the mysterious `corrplot`-function. 2) When you load the file, you probably have `NA` values on the entries above the diagonal. This could also be an issue (despite having specified `type="lower"`)

Comment: If the data is not square, we can make it square: reshape from wide to long, then get all gene combos, then merge, then reshape it back to long to wide, and finally convert to matrix.

Comment: @MrGumble I've also add this line before: `m[is.na(m)] <- 0`, and I'd added this argument too: `is.corr = FALSE` but it is not working

Comment: You do not have a "lower" matrix. You have part of a lower matrix and a diagonal. You need columns for CD274 and LAG3. Then you can set the diagonal and the upper triangle to missing values.